# PrepareStatement not working in select query java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, where-clause

```
String checkq="select * from "+Dbc.TB_COMPANY+" where cmp_name=? and cmp_id!=?";
        pst=con.prepareStatement(checkq);
                pst.setString(1,"test"); pst.setString(2,"2")
        rs=st.executeQuery(checkq);
```

**shows**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''13a'' and cmp_id!=3' at line 1

Comment: It would be really useful if you would quote the error relevant to the code. Your code isn't setting the values `13a` or `3`, but the error clearly relates to a statement using those values.

Comment: *''13a'' and cmp_id!=3'* is not the exact statement of the exception as the `setString` values are always shown inside single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String checkq="select * from "+Dbc.TB_COMPANY+" where cmp_name=? and cmp_id!=?";
        pst=con.prepareStatement(checkq);
                pst.setString(1,"test"); pst.setString(2,"2")
        rs=pst.executeQuery(checkq);
```

you are using both statement and prepareStatement

make sure to use prepareStatement

Comment: Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `st.executeQuery` and passing in `checkq`, which makes me think `st` is a `Statement` instance. The string in `checkq` is not, of course, a valid SQL statement — it has `PreparedStatement` placeholders in it. You should be calling `executeQuery` on the **`PreparedStatement`** instead (and not using a simple `Statement` at all):

```
String checkq="select * from "+Dbc.TB_COMPANY+" where cmp_name=? and cmp_id!=?";
pst=con.prepareStatement(checkq);
pst.setString(1,"test");
pst.setString(2,"2")
// Not: rs=st.executeQuery(checkq);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @rak: JDBC is not broken, if you change the third line to `pst.setString(1, "test'")`, it will insert that into the table, provided that's a column that accepts text.

Comment: yeah, actually i get the value from textfield in that time it didn't work

i get the value as test = request.getParameter('text_field_name');

pst.setStrting(1,test);